# Visio Protection: Lock line width but allow colour change

Tags: microsoft-visio, shapes

I'm creating a Visio shape using basic shapes. I'd like to lock the line width of my elements, and I'd also like to allow colours to be changed.

If I select the Developer > Protection > Format option, I can toggle protection of both line width and colour (with the one action).

Is there any way I can toggle each parameter separately?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can guard the line weight cell for the shape in its shapesheet, and leave the color cell editable.

[image: The cell to guard]